# derivative of complex function

Tags: complex-analysis, derivatives, complex-numbers

i want to ask question related to about derivative of complex  function:

if $f(z)$ is  differentiable in a  connected  open set $R$ and if $f'(z)=0$, through $R$,then $f(z)$ is constant  in $R$

i want to know why differentiable  necessary in this case?suppose that  in generally we have
following matlab code

syms a b
$z=a+b*i$

result is

a + b*i

after differentiation

diff(z)

ans =

i

now reason why i have  tried is to say,that in real  numbers  if  $f'(x)=0$then $f(x)=c$  for some  number,let say  $c=5$, so is it same  for complex numbers or there important is to say that function is also differentiable?thanks in advance

Comment: The function being differentiable means $f'$ exists. Without differentiability, you can't formulate the condition $f' = 0$.

Comment: aaa,so it means that it is identity,not additional condition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although Daniel Fischer's comment is on target, a little  more can be said. Differentiability in a complex domain (or in $\mathbb R^n$) is quite a strong condition; can it be relaxed? The answer is yes.

> Let $U\subset \mathbb R^n$ be a connected open set. Suppose $f:U\to\mathbb R$ is a function such that the partial derivatives $\partial f/\partial x_i$ exist and are zero at every point. Then $f$ is constant.

Note that the above can be used for complex-valued and vector-valued functions too, by applying the result to each component (like real and imaginary parts) separately.

The proof of the claim is in two steps:

1. By the mean value  theorem from real analysis, $f$ is constant on every line segment contained in $U$ and parallel to one of coordinate axes.
2. Any two points of $U$ can be joined by a   path that consists of finitely many segments of the above form.